# (PHP) Using oauth and service accounts to access private Google Photos (Picasa Web) API info

Tags: php, picasa, service-accounts, google-photos

I would like to access info from a private Google Photos album owned by an account which I have access to. Could I log in as the owner of the album to obtain a token and access data? Or would a service account be able to access the data? I know the Picasa API is outdated, however this is the easiest way for me to mass-store photos and videos I want to publish on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so what I found, if you did make an old web album, like when Picasa was still around, it would have public read access. This is the only way to do this, but now I am working on using Imgur to do the same thing.